# How to save images in a default folder automatically in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible to set default folder in FileReference save() function. I know if we use file.save(bitmapImage, "filename"), it will open the file browser dialogue box to save the file.

what I want is, when someone click on the save button, the flash application should automatically save the bitmap image in a desktop folder(The folder should also be created if it is not available).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Flash(web) can't save automatically, because it is access-restricted for security.

However, Adobe AIR can save automatically by using flash.filesystem.File and flash.filesystem.FileStream.